# How to split a field into characters in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to check if two fields in a field have common characters

```
first second // looking for "s"
third fourth // looking for "t" or "h" or "r"
some that
```

I want to print only the first two lines in which the fields have at least one common character.

I read the fields as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" ";} CONDITION {print $0}' file.txt
```

In the CONDITION, I need to split one field into characters and check their existence in the other field.

```
// for $1
BEGIN{FS=""}
  { i=0; while(i<=NF) {
   CHECK in $2; i++;
  } print $0 }
```

but I am not sure how I should bring the fields (`$1` and `$2`) to the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex way:

```
awk 'NF>=2 {
   s = $1
   p = $2
   gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:blank:]_]/, "\\\\&", p)
   sub("[" p "]", "", s)
}
s != $1' file
```

```
first second // looking for "s"
third fourth // looking for "t" or "h" or "r"
```

Here we use `sub` function to make a bracket expression i.e. `[...]` where `...` is `$2` and then remove there characters from `$1`. If `$1` is not  equal to `s` (saved value of `$1`) then there is still one common character between first 2 fields.

Comment: I got your approach, but it has two problems: (i) the matching character is dropped from the output (it is the case in your output too), (ii) the regex breaks if we have an illegal character like `-`.

Answer (score 2):

a straightforward implementation can be

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($1);i++) 
          if(index($2,substr($1,i,1))) 
            {print; next}}' file

first second
third fourth
```

or,

```
$ awk '{n=split($1,f,""); 
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
          if(index($2,f[i])) 
            {print; next}}' file
```

Comment: `split($1,f,"")` is undefined behavior per POSIX. It'll do what you want in GNU awk but not in some other awks. The first script is concise, portable and robust though - nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete chars
    for (i=1; i<=length($1); i++) {
        chars[substr($1,i,1)]
    }
    for (i=1; i<=length($2); i++) {
        if (substr($2,i,1) in chars) {
            print
            next
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
first second // looking for "s"
third fourth // looking for "t" or "h" or "r"
```